# Sparse matrices with lots of repeated elements in Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a triangular sparse matrix of dimension n where the only coefficients that appear are c_1, c_2,...c_n. There are at most n repetitions of a single coefficient in the matrix. Is there any way to use the fact that there are many elements of the matrix that are the same and use much less memory instead of assigning the same value to many different (row, column) and not exploiting the fact that many are the same. At the end of the day I want to apply the inverse of the said matrix to an arbitrary vector.

Thank you!

Comment: What is c_1, c_2, etc.? Do you mean c_11, c_21, ...? Please be more specific? How are you computing the inverse? With the `scipy` library also?

Comment: A sparse matrix will have a `data` value for each non-zero element.

Comment: Yes you probably could compress it a bit in memory by factorizing or something. No, it wouldn't be worth it. Also when you invert it it's probably going to end up pretty dense so I'd worry a lot more about that step.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. The point is that there are at most n different elements in the n x n matrix, so there is a lot of repetition. I wouldn't need the explicit inverse as much as solve the system Av=b where A is the matrix, b is a given vector and we are seeking v. I understand the sparse package has an algorithm for solving such linear problems.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

as far as I know there's no scipy implementation of this but in principle you could store a list of `n` matrix indices, `n` data indices, and `k<=n` data values. Where each data index is between 0 and `k-1` and tells you which of the possible data values that index has. If `k<<n` this could potentially save a lot of memory

Answer (score -1):

Definitely, you can use the sparse matrix data structures from 'scipy.sparse'. If you know the values tend to group in certain patterns you can use specific sparse matrix structures optimized for that pattern. If the values group along diagonals use 'dia_matrix', columns use 'csc_matrix', rows use 'csr_matrix', and blocks use 'bsr_matrix'.

Comment: Those sparse formats don't save on memory, at least not in the sense that the OP probably wants.